# Importing DBC files from OrCAD to Altium Designer

Tags: xml, import

I'm trying to import some DBC files using this [manual](https://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/((OrCAD+CIS+Import))_AD#OrCADCISImport-ImportingOrCADCISFiles). But I'm getting the error "dbc file with xml format is not supported right now".
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altium support answered something like this:
Altium can only import DBC files in binary format, like they were in OrCAD 9.2 or older.

The other way is to create OLB and LLB, import them separately and manually create DbLib.